# How to use the standard functions after modification ListView

Tags: android, listview

I use [this Pull-to-Refresh](https://github.com/JoeDailey/Android-Simple-Pull-to-Refresh), it works, but after the installation can not call standard functions for listView, such as:

```
    public static RefreshableListView lv = (RefreshableListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView); //this work

lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(longClickListener); //don`t work
lv.setSelection(listViewCountPosition); //don`t work
Parcelable state = lv.onSaveInstanceState(); //don`t work
lv.onRestoreInstanceState(state);    //don`t work
```

Compiler writes error.

Comment: What errors? Please post your logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RefreshableListView implements FrameLayout ( not listview). Listview is added as a child to the FrameLayout. You have to call getListView() for list view instance.

something like this..

```
  public RefreshableListView lv = (RefreshableListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
  lv.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(longClickListener);
```